# getting the object value in key in dictionary

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary with key-value pair populated from JSON returned data.What I wish to do is use the dictionary to populate UITableView.

I have this structure for table:

[Product Name]
   By [Manufacturer Name]

What this means is that key is Product Name and Value is Manufacturer Name. I need to get the name of the key and the name of the value. How can this be done? and is it possible without for-loop?

Comment: What do u mean by name of the key and name of the value?

Comment: put your JSON data and after tell us what u want ...

Comment: I am away from my PC @ work. but thanks anyway guys for posting your answers. will try and write back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use the `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:` method. The following code builds a list of the strings you require.

```
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];

[dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: ^(NSString *key, NSString *object, BOOL *stop) {
    [names addObject[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ By %@",key, object]];
}];
```

Comment: + 1 I'd actually rather use a simple loop to extract from dictionaries due to it's simplicity. Blocks like these are not so intuitive when wandered upon in code. However, it's probably the best solution.

Comment: @Da_smokes Thank you. I think it comes down to personal taste and level of comfort with them to a certain extent. Most important factor though is sensible naming.

Comment: Thank you very much @CarlVeazey for the solution. Surely will be tested and used if works.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `keyEnumerator` of `NSDictionary` and for each key look up the value. This could look something like this:

```
for (NSString *p in dict)
{
    NSString *m = [dict objectForKey:p];
    // do something with (p,m)
}
```

You should not be concerned with avoiding `for`-loops. After all, something like a `for` loop will always happen somewhere underneath.

Comment: This looks like the thing i need. Unfortunately I am away from home now and can't check. But as long as I can access key and value both with their content then it is good.

Comment: This doesn't work. It prints only the first record multiple types. but yes it does get the key and value but it didn't work totally

Comment: Oh no mate that wasn't the problem because I fixed it before you did in my code anyway. But it still doesn't work. it just prints the name o Jane and student in each table row.

Comment: This must be an independent problem with populating the table. You can check that for yourself with `NSLog(@"%@, %@", p, m);`. The code I show you is correct.

Comment: Perhaps you could try my edits for being absolutely sure. Let me know. The edits use something called "fast enumeration".

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are dynamic from json then you can use

```
 NSArray *keys = [dictionary allkeys];
```

Then in the table View Cell for row at index path method you can populate the table view with the corresponding keys and their values.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray * keys = [results allKeys];

for (int i = 0;i<[keys count];c++){
 NSString* productName = [key objectAtIndex:i];
 NSString* manufacturerName = [results objectForKey:productName];
}
```

Hope this helps...

I have assumed the name as strings, you can change the type according to your situation..

Comment: I'd suggest using fast enumeration or block-based enumeration, and also not capitalize the names of local variables.